# How do I remove the codecracker Nuget package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, roslyn-code-analysis

I installed the Nuget Codecracker.csharp package in VS2015, as a trial. I then uninstalled it using the Solution Explorer "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" tool. This now shows the packages as being uninstalled - BUT - the solution won't build because several projects complain about missing components of CodeCracker:

> "CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   '....\packages\codecracker.CSharp.1.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CodeCracker.Common.dll'
>   could not be found 21>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   '....\packages\codecracker.CSharp.1.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CodeCracker.CSharp.dll'
>   could not be found"

There is no  documentation on the Codecracker Github or other websites, and no means of contacting the team other than via a jabber site that is permanently down.

How to clean this up so my solution builds again?

Comment: Sounds like the package uninstaller was not written we and did not clean everything up. Look in your assembly references for the projects failing to build and check for references to codecracker that are obviously nor longer available and remove them.

Comment: The dll maybe have been referenced before or instead of a nuget package install.  You might have to manually remove the reference in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: No, they're not referenced in Solution Explorer. But some of the project files did contain an IncludeGroup section that referred to these dlls (see comment on the next answer below) which I have now edited out with Notepad, and that solves the problem. I think there must be something wrong with the package uninstaller for Codecracker.

Answer (score 0):

Unload your Projects and remove following `ItemGroup` from your .csproj files:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\codecracker.CSharp.1.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CodeCracker.Common.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\codecracker.CSharp.1.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CodeCracker.CSharp.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Already removed, but the problem was eventually traced to several project files that had retained an IncludeGroup section referencing the codecracker dlls. Looks like there is some issue with Nuget not cleanly removing this package from the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio:Tools > Extension and Update > CodeCracker.Csharp and then UnInstall it.